# How to get real-time JFrame update with a button

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a question for my Java GUI program so, here it is.

I've been working on this project for a few hours today and I have the entire "Login" window set-up, but there's one thing that doesn't seem to be working for me. I have a label underneath the "Login" form and it's not updating if I get the password or the username wrong with a different string value. Here's the code:

```
package main;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

import java.awt.Window.Type;

import javax.swing.JPasswordField;


public class Login {

private JFrame frmConsoleappReborn;
private JTextField textField_1;
private JPasswordField passwordField;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Login window = new Login();
                window.frmConsoleappReborn.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Login() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frmConsoleappReborn = new JFrame();
    frmConsoleappReborn.setType(Type.UTILITY);
    frmConsoleappReborn.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
    frmConsoleappReborn.setTitle("ConsoleApp Reborn");
    frmConsoleappReborn.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 255));
    frmConsoleappReborn.getContentPane().setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    frmConsoleappReborn.setBounds(100, 100, 565, 369);
    frmConsoleappReborn.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frmConsoleappReborn.getContentPane().setLayout(null);



    JLabel lblWelcomeToMy = new JLabel("Welcome to my amazing program!");
    lblWelcomeToMy.setForeground(new Color(255, 0, 0));
    lblWelcomeToMy.setBounds(174, 11, 242, 14);
    frmConsoleappReborn.getContentPane().add(lblWelcomeToMy);

    JLabel lblUserName = new JLabel("User name");
    lblUserName.setForeground(new Color(255, 0, 0));
    lblUserName.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    lblUserName.setBounds(158, 70, 67, 25);
    frmConsoleappReborn.getContentPane().add(lblUserName);

    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
    textField_1.setBackground(new Color(255, 0, 0));
    textField_1.setColumns(10);
    textField_1.setBounds(235, 72, 118, 20);
    frmConsoleappReborn.getContentPane().add(textField_1);

    JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password");
    lblPassword.setForeground(new Color(255, 0, 0));
    lblPassword.setBounds(158, 146, 76, 14);
    frmConsoleappReborn.getContentPane().add(lblPassword);

    passwordField = new JPasswordField();
    passwordField.setBackground(Color.RED);
    passwordField.setBounds(235, 143, 118, 20);
    frmConsoleappReborn.getContentPane().add(passwordField);

    JLabel loginStatus = new JLabel("Your login status will show up here.");
    loginStatus.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    loginStatus.setBounds(184, 195, 219, 14);
    frmConsoleappReborn.getContentPane().add(loginStatus);

    JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
    btnLogin.setBounds(151, 228, 256, 61);
    frmConsoleappReborn.getContentPane().add(btnLogin);
    btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if(textField_1.getText().equals("Admin"))
        {
            if(passwordField.getText().equals("Admin"))
            {
            loginStatus.setText("Login successful!");
            } else {
                loginStatus.setText("Login failed. Please check password.");
            }
        } else {
            loginStatus.setText("Login failed. Please check username");
        }
        }
    });

}
}
```

All the best,

Groax

Comment: Please remove all extraneous code. I know that I, and probably many others, don't want to read through a hundred lines of code to find the five that matter.

Comment: "It's not updating when I get the password wrong," are you implying that it does update the label when you get the password correct? You get the "login successful" message but not the "login failed" messages? Also, what Jashaszun said; please edit out the imports at least, if not more.

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: And your program works fine for me

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer I have no idea what the problem was before, because it just started working for me about 5-10 minutes ago :T Well thanks again :).